# NodeJS does not respond to CURL Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, mongojs

Im using NodeJS to perform som Queries to a MongoDB.
I've set up the routing so when

```
     http://127.0.0.1:8888/GetAllCities
```

is called, a function name GetAllCities will run on the server and perform a MongoDB query and return the result.
This works just fine when I try to visit the page directly in my browser.
But when I try to make a CURL request the response is empty.

This is my jquery Ajaxcall

```
    function makeCall(urlToCall, method)
    {
        var params = "url=" + urlToCall + method;
        if(app === "PHP")
        {
            params += "&PHP=PHP";
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "phpProxy.php",
            data: params,
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                document.write(app + ' -- Starting round ' + (i+1) + "<br />");
                document.write('URL: ' + params + "<br />");
                startTime = new Date().getTime();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                endTime = new Date().getTime();
                totalTime = endTime - startTime;
                if(totalTime > highest)
                {
                    highest = totalTime;
                }
                if(totalTime < lowest)
                {
                    lowest = totalTime;
                }
                var row = {};
                row.app = app;
                row.operation = method;
                row.totalTime = totalTime;
                row.run = i+1;
                row.date = new Date();
                document.write('\tTotal time: <strong>' + totalTime + 'ms</strong>' + "<br />");
                times.push(row);
                document.write(data + "<br />");
                document.write('Round done\n' + "<br />" + "<br />");
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log('Error');
                console.log(err);
            },
            complete: function()
            {
                i++;
                if(i < 50)
                {
                    makeCall(urlToCall, method);
                }
                else
                {
                    var sum = 0;
                    for(var j = 0; j < times.length; j++)
                    {
                        sum += parseInt(times[j].totalTime);
                    }
                    var avg = sum/times.length;
                    $('body').prepend('<h3>Slowest: ' + highest + 'ms</h3>');
                    $('body').prepend('<h3>Fastest: ' + lowest + 'ms</h3>');
                    $('body').prepend('<h3>Average: ' + avg + 'ms</h3>');

                    myApp.saveToDb(times);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is my PHPPROXY FILE:

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

$url = $_POST['url'];

$curl=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

if(isset($_POST['PHP']))
{
    $params = array('a' => 'php');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
}
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $result;
```

And this is my NODEJS requesthandlerfile.

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var querystring = require("querystring");



function GetAllCities(response)
{
  console.log('Request recieved');
  var databaseUrl = "exjobb";
  var collections = ["cities"]
  var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections);
  db.cities.find(function(err, cities) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
    response.write(cities.length + " rows selected from the Database");
    response.end();
    db.close();
  });
}

function GetAllCitiesWhere(response)
{

  var databaseUrl = "exjobb";
  var collections = ["cities"]
  var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections);
  db.cities.find({state: "AL"}, function(err, cities) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
  response.write(cities.length + " rows selected from the Database");
  response.end();
  }); 
}

exports.start = start;
exports.GetAllCities = GetAllCities;
exports.GetAllCitiesWhere = GetAllCitiesWhere;
```

TLDR; My code works on a direct GET when visiting the page in a browser, but not when making ajax request, why?
You can find all code [here](https://github.com/josefottosson/exjobb/tree/master/nodeJS)

Comment: Have you verified that `curl` is running currectly from the PHP script? (Does your PHP script fetch any pages correctly? Have you tested running `curl` directly from the command line?)

Comment: Also, your PHP script is doing a `curl` `POST` request rather than a `GET`; could that be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the node.js code that sets up the routes/server?

Comment: You can find it here https://github.com/josefottosson/exjobb/tree/master/nodeJS
But I have solved it now, I changed my PHP proxy to the following settings
`$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

 $url = $_POST['url'];

 $curl=curl_init();
 
 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
     CURLOPT_URL => $url,
     CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Josefs PHPPROXY'
 ));

 $result = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);

 echo $result;`
Thanks apsillers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved as noted in the comments.

The problem was this line in my curl request.

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
```

I changed my PHP proxy to the following settings:

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];   
$url = $_POST['url'];   
$curl=curl_init();      
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => $url,CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Josefs PHPPROXY'));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
```